# Maven starts container for each IntegrationTest

Tags: maven, containers, integration-testing, wildfly, jboss-arquillian

I setup Arquillian with "embedded" wildfly (it's technically not embedded, the entire wildfly distribution will be unpacked into target folder and used as a managed container) and everything works well so far. However, when I run my entire test suite with maven, it starts up the container for each Integrationtest. Is there a way to tell maven to only startup wildfly once and use that container instance for all integration tests?
Here's an extract of my pom file and the arquillian.xml

pom.xml:

```
<profile>
  <id>wildfly-managed</id>
  <activation>
    <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
</activation>
<!-- dependencies for Wildfly  -->
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
        <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-managed</artifactId>
        <version>8.2.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
        <artifactId>wildfly-embedded</artifactId>
        <version>8.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
        </testResource>
        <testResource>
            <directory>src/test/resources/META-INF</directory>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.8</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>unpack</id>
                    <phase>process-test-classes</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>unpack</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
                                <artifactId>wildfly-dist</artifactId>
                                <version>${version.wildfly}</version>
                                <type>zip</type>
                                <overWrite>false</overWrite>
                                <outputDirectory>target</outputDirectory>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <systemPropertyVariables>
                            <arquillian.launch>wildfly-managed</arquillian.launch>
                            <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                            <jboss.home>${project.basedir}/target/wildfly-8.2.0.Final</jboss.home>
                            <module.path>${project.basedir}/target/wildfly-8.2.0.Final/modules</module.path>
                        </systemPropertyVariables>
                        <redirectTestOutputToFile>false</redirectTestOutputToFile>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.1</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
                    <version>5.0.1</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

arquillian.xml:

```
<container qualifier="wildfly-managed" default="true">
    <configuration>
        <property name="jbossHome">${jboss.home}</property>
        <property name="outputToConsole">true</property>
        <property name="allowConnectingToRunningServer">true</property>
        <property name="javaVmArguments">-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xdebug
            -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8787
        </property>
    </configuration>
</container>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you've got both the `wildfly-embedded` and `wildfly-arquillian-container-managed` defined? You should only have one or the other. Side note the `module.path` shouldn't be required.

Comment: no specific reason, but I removed wildfly-embedded now. the problem still persists though

Comment: Are your integration tests in different maven modules are all in the same module? By default if they're all in the same maven module it should be starting the server once.

Comment: yes, it's all one module, one single pom file

Comment: Interesting, I'm not sure I've seen this before but I've only used Arquillian in unit tests. I assume none of your tests are shutting down ore reloading the server right?

Comment: I just did a test with the `maven-failsafe-plugin` and the server only started once for me. Do you by chance of some log file examples?

Comment: Do you mean a maven log? I do have a theory now though. My tests run all out of order, some unittests first, then a couple integrationtests and again some unittests followed by integrationtests again. maybe I need to tell maven to properly separate them? If so, examples are welcome

Comment: In WildFly integration tests are in a separate maven module. You could do that or possibly use a `@Suite` and/or categories.